# Rails 4 find parent associations which are missing certain child associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

I am trying to query for which parent (category) records DON'T have ha child record (post) with a given property (author.id).

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :category
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I am trying to find which categories an author has NEVER posted in.  The idea is to get an array of categories that do not have posts by a GIVEN author, they can have OTHER posts...just not by the specific author

```
@author_unused_categories = @author.unused_categories


class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

  def unused_categories
    categories = Categories.all
    author_used_categories = Post.where(author_id: self.id).select(:category).uniq ??????
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
categories = Author.includes(posts: :category).select('category.id AS category_id').map(&:category_id)

unused_categories = Category.where.not(id: categories)
```